# How do I set HTML form values into SESSION variables?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, session

I have a html form with 16 fields (https://secure.high-speed-business-club.com//TEMPLATE-order-form-module/?affiliate=0).

What is the best way to capture all of these field values to be stored as SESSION variables? Can it be done with an array or best to assign each field to individual session variables one by one?

I've tried with this code, but it is not working:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) {
       $_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['Contact0FirstName']; 
    }
?>
```

Looking for some elaboration on a previously asked and subsequently closed question. Would love some more insight into how SESSIONs are supposed to work, hence I have asked a more direct question.

Comment: same was as i told you last time you posted

Answer (score 2):

Your code is actually correct, anyway you could inject `$_POST` array directly in your session as follow

```
$_SESSION['post_array'] = $_POST;
```

Now you can access all array by `$_SESSION['post']['nameofpostfieldhere'];`

All your field are stored in `$_SESSION['post']` array with all name=>value relations

Comment: told him the same thing last time he asked - maybe he will take note this time :0

Comment: Yes i just checked :)

Comment: Thanks all. And thanks especially to Dagon for his response on the last. I simply required a little more elaboration for the concept to make sense. Thanks, Fabio for that.

I've tested the code you have provided and I still can't seem to get the SESSION vars to print in a test at the bottom. Is it actually possible this form doesn't use POST?

Comment: Did you start session at the very beginning of your script?